# How to run the "spherecluster" package with scikit-learn version 0.24 from python (ModuleNotFoundError)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda, pypi

I need to import the module "spherecluster" from https://github.com/jasonlaska/spherecluster . (python/pipy)
But it does not work with recent versions of the scikit-learn package version > 0.24 .

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cluster.k_means_'
```

I found that `k_means_` was renamed in future versions. (code structure changed)

How to fix this?

Do I need to completely rewrite the code from spherecluster to run with the current sklearn version?

Answer (score 0):

[This is an open issue on the package](https://github.com/jasonlaska/spherecluster/pull/34), which, judging from the lack of responsiveness of the author(s), appears neglected. Keep bothering them and voice your support for the PR.

Otherwise, the proper solution is to constrain a Conda environment to use only a compatible version of scikit-learn.

```bash
## create a new env with the constraint
conda create -n spherecluster python=3.7 pip scikit-learn=0.22

## activate it
conda activate spherecluster

## install the package from 
pip install spherecluster
```

A less proper solution would be to install the `spherecluster` package from the PR branch:

```bash
conda activate your_env
pip install git+https://github.com/rfayat/spherecluster.git@scikit_update
```